# How to redo code to prompt for read and input at top of loop prior to range check

Tags: c

I am still new to C program, but I am learning.  I received some feed back that I am not entirely sure how to accomplish and am hoping that I am hoping someone here might be able to shed some light on please.  I was told that it isn't a good idea to treat the first guess any differently than any other guesses by putting it before the start of the loop.  I should treat all of the guesses the same.  So I should initialize guess to 0 before the start of the loop and put the code to prompt for and read the input at the top of the loop so that the input is read before the range check.  How or what do I need to change in my code to accomplish this?  I believe I addressed initializing the guess to 0 right at the top, but I am not sure about the rest or it that is right.
Thank you,
Annette

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

    int guess = 0;
    time_t t;
    int randNumber;
    int numberOfGuess;


    /*srand is used to seed the random number so that it is different every time.  This is giving the
    random number an initial base that the rand() can use to offset with a random number.*/
    srand(time(&t));

    /*This will initialize a random number between 0 and 20, but the +1 at the end adds a number so the
    created random number falls anywhere from 1 through 20*/
    randNumber = (rand()% 20) +1;

    /*Prompt the user to input a random number between 1 and 20 and increase the numberOfGuess counter
    by 1*/
    printf("Let's play a guessing game and see how many times it takes you to guess a preselected ");
    printf("random number between 1 - 20.\n");
    printf("Please guess a number between 1 and 20:\t");
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    /*This sets the while loop to validate if the guess is not the randNumber, which enables an escape once
    the guess is equal to the randNumber.*/
    while (guess != randNumber)
    {

        /*If the guess is lower than or equal to 0 or the guess is greater than 20, I print out the statement
        notifying the user and prompting the user to enter a new guess.  It is at this point that I also added
        a statement to increase the numberOfGuess count by 1 as this should be counted towards the guess total*/
        if (guess <= 0 || guess > 20)
        {
            printf("\nThe number guessed isn't between 1 and 20, please enter a new guess:  ");
            numberOfGuess++;
            scanf("%d", &guess);
        }

        /*If the guess in higher than the randNumber, I let the user know and ask the user to
        enter another guess and I added another statement to increase the numberOfGuess count
        by 1 as this should be counted towards the guess total*/
        else
        {
            if(guess > randNumber)
            {
                printf("\nYour guess of %d is too high, guess again:  ", guess);
                numberOfGuess++;
                scanf("%d", &guess);
            }

            /*If the guess in lower than the randNumber, I let the user know and ask the user to
            enter another guess and I added another statement to increase the numberOfGuess count
            by 1 as this should be counted towards the guess total*/

            else
            {
                if(guess < randNumber)
                {
                    printf("\nYour guess of %d is too low, guess again:  ", guess);
                    numberOfGuess++;
                    scanf("%d", &guess);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    /*The last item for this tasks prints the results with the correct guessed number, the number of guesses
     and the last statement to increase the numberOfGuess count by 1 as this should be counted towards the guess total.
     Also, this capture the count if the user's guess is correct the first time.  The while loop and if..else statements
     would not capture the count for a correct guess
     */
    numberOfGuess++;
    printf("\nYou guessed it, the number was %d and it took you %d guess(s)!", guess, numberOfGuess);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By moving the call to `scanf()` inside and to the top of the loop and incrementing the `numberofGuess` right behind, you avoid duplicating the code with every `if/else` branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int guess = 0;
    int randNumber;
    int numberOfGuess;
    const char * msg = "Please guess a number between 1 and 20:\t";

    /*srand is used to seed the random number so that it is different every time.  This is giving the
    random number an initial base that the rand() can use to offset with a random number.*/
    srand(time(NULL));

    /*This will initialize a random number between 0 and 20, but the +1 at the end adds a number so the
    created random number falls anywhere from 1 through 20*/
    randNumber = (rand()% 20) +1;

    /*Prompt the user to input a random number between 1 and 20 and increase the numberOfGuess counter
    by 1*/
    printf("Let's play a guessing game and see how many times it takes you to guess a preselected ");
    printf("random number between 1 - 20.\n");

    /*This sets the while loop to validate if the guess is not the randNumber, which enables an escape once
    the guess is equal to the randNumber.*/
    do
    {
        numberOfGuess += 1;
        printf(msg, guess);
        scanf("%d", &guess);

        /*If the guess is lower than or equal to 0 or the guess is greater than 20, I print out the statement
          notifying the user and prompting the user to enter a new guess.  It is at this point that I also added
          a statement to increase the numberOfGuess count by 1 as this should be counted towards the guess total*/
        if (guess <= 0 || guess > 20)
        {
            msg = "\nThe number guessed isn't between 1 and 20, please enter a new guess:  ";
        }

        /*If the guess in higher than the randNumber, I let the user know and ask the user to
          enter another guess and I added another statement to increase the numberOfGuess count
          by 1 as this should be counted towards the guess total*/
        else if(guess > randNumber)
        {
          msg = "\nYour guess of %d is too high, guess again:  ";
        }
             
        /*If the guess in lower than the randNumber, I let the user know and ask the user to
          enter another guess and I added another statement to increase the numberOfGuess count
          by 1 as this should be counted towards the guess total*/
        else if(guess < randNumber)
        {
          msg = "\nYour guess of %d is too low, guess again:  ";
        }
    } while (guess != randNumber);

    /*The last item for this tasks prints the results with the correct guessed number, the number of guesses
     and the last statement to increase the numberOfGuess count by 1 as this should be counted towards the guess total.
     Also, this capture the count if the user's guess is correct the first time.  The while loop and if..else statements
     would not capture the count for a correct guess
     */
    printf("\nYou guessed it, the number was %d and it took you %d guess(s)!\n",
           guess, numberOfGuess);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Let's play a guessing game and see how many times it takes you to guess a preselected random number between 1 - 20.
Please guess a number between 1 and 20: 10

Your guess of 10 is too low, guess again:  15

Your guess of 15 is too low, guess again:  17

You guessed it, the number was 17 and it took you 3 guess(s)!
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

I use a `do while` but of course you can also do a `for(;;)` or equivalent and in the `if ... else if ...` serial add a final `else break;` to not check *guess* an additional time (but probably the compiler optimize the current code to not do it)

Note I give *NULL* in argument to the function `time()` because I don't need to save the current time.

As you can see I increment *numberOfGuess* and call `scanf` only one time, that simplify. There is also only one `printf` in the loop but several assignments to set the right format.

The first time `printf(msg, guess);` is executed the format does not contain a `%d` so the argument *guess* is unused, this is not a problem.

But there is huge problem, in case the user does not enter a valid integer the program loops without ending, it is needed to check the result of `scanf` and bypass the invalid input for instance flushing the full line, so for instance replacing :

```
scanf("%d", &guess);

/*If the guess is lower than or equal to 0 or the guess is greater than 20, I print out the statement
  notifying the user and prompting the user to enter a new guess.  It is at this point that I also added
  a statement to increase the numberOfGuess count by 1 as this should be counted towards the guess total*/
if (guess <= 0 || guess > 20)
```

by :

```
if (scanf("%d", &guess) != 1)
{
  /* invalid input, flush all the line */
  while ((guess = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    if (guess == EOF)
    {
      puts("abort game");
      return 0;
    }
  }
  guess = 0; /* to not be the search value whatever \n encoding */
  msg = "\ninvalid input, it was not a number, please enter a new guess:  ";
}

/*If the guess is lower than or equal to 0 or the guess is greater than 20, I print out the statement
  notifying the user and prompting the user to enter a new guess.  It is at this point that I also added
  a statement to increase the numberOfGuess count by 1 as this should be counted towards the guess total*/
else if (guess <= 0 || guess > 20)
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Let's play a guessing game and see how many times it takes you to guess a preselected random number between 1 - 20.
Please guess a number between 1 and 20: qsd

invalid input, it was not a number, please enter a new guess:  qsd

invalid input, it was not a number, please enter a new guess:  1

Your guess of 1 is too low, guess again:  qsd

invalid input, it was not a number, please enter a new guess:  ^C
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

When you read a value I encourage you to *never* suppose it is valid and to *always* check it is.